# What is the mechanism for charge distribution in an infinitely long conducting wire?

Tags: ac, charge, line

If we supply along conducting wire conductor an AC supply, is the charge distribution inside the wire similar to the image given below? Also, do electrons push each other to generate this charge distribution.

[image]

Comment: Is the other end of the source floating?

Comment: If the piece of infinitey long wire is connected to a voltage source, is there any reference or return path? If there is one electrode but no another electrode, how would the system work?

Answer (score 0):

> is the charge distribution inside the wire similar to the image given below?

No. Inside the interior of the wire, the net charge density is very close to 0. Virtually all of the net charge density in a uniform wire is on the surface.

> do electrons push each other to generate this charge distribution.

No. At least at low frequencies, current flows fairly uniformly throughout the interior of the wire, where (as explained above) the net charge density is essentially zero. The current flow in the interior of the wire is caused by the non-zero charge density on the surface creating an electric field. This electric field causes electrons to accelerate within the wire. However, after a very, very short distance, the electrons collide with atoms in the wire and their motion becomes random (i.e. heat). The electric field then re-accelerates the electrons, and this process is what causes current.

As the frequency of the current is increased there is less current in the center of the wire and greater current near the surface. At very high frequencies, the current is almost completely confined near the surface, and almost none is in the center. At those very high frequencies, the net charge and the current are both near or on the surface. So in that case it may appear that the electrons are pushing each other like water molecules pushing each other in a pipe. But in general, the "water flow" model of electricity is not physically accurate even though it provides a useful (though inaccurate) analogy to explain some electrical phenomena like Ohm's Law.